# Partial application with changing of return type

Tags: f#

I have a function to read a byte from an array:

```
let readByte array address =   (* []<byte> -> int -> byte *)
    (* ... *)
```

In an other function where I use this function very often, I'd like to do partial application:

```
let myOtherFunction array =
    let readByteAsInt = readByte array
    (* ... *)
    let x = readByteAsInt address
```

Basically this works. In my example `x` is now of type `byte` but I would need it as an `int`. In this simple example I could cast the return value when assigning to `x` but as I said, I use `readByteAsInt` very often and I don't want to do the cast on every call.

I have tried

```
let readByteAsInt = int (readByte array)
```

and

```
let readByteAsInt = readByte array |> int
```

but both result in an error when calling `readByteAsInt`:

> FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied

How can I change the return type of the partial application?

Changing the signature of `readByte` to return an `int` is not an option as I *do* need `byte` elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readByte array` is a function, and `int` is another function; you want to compose them so that the output of `readByte array` becomes the input of `int`. You can write `readByte array >> int` - note that it's `>>` for composition, instead of `|>` for application.

Answer (score 2):

Like @kaya3 mentioned, you can use function composition with (<<) or (>>). But even without function application or composition, you could just create another function directly with a parameter instead.

```
let readByteAsInt pos = int (readByte array pos)
let readByteAsInt pos = readByte array pos |> int
```

Or the function compositon way

```
let readByteAsInt = int << readByte array
let readByteAsInt = readByte array >> int
```

Keep in mind, that function composition, does not always work in F# when the function has a generic input, then you must define a function with arguments explicitly.